# Spring SAML implementation cannot resolve reference to bean

Tags: java, spring-security, vaadin, saml, spring-saml

On my Vaadin application project I want to integrate spring-security-SAML extension. I downloaded source code from spring security extension page. Based on manual I packaged extension using mvn package and deployed it on local maven repository using mvn deploy command. Everything goes right. A compiled extension appeared on the maven repository. So I included it into project pom.xml file as dependency like this:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security.extensions</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-saml2-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0-RC1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
```

After that I updated maven project and found spring-security-saml2-core-1.0.0-RC1-SNAPSHOT.jar inside maven dependency directory (I am using eclipse IDE with Maven). The next thing what I did, was **appLicationContext.xml** file editing. **applicationContext.xml** file is included throught the web.xml. So I added lines below to **appLicationContext.xml** file:

```
    <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.0.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

    <context:annotation-config />
    <context:component-scan base-package="org.springframework.security.saml"/>

    <security:http entry-point-ref="samlEntryPoint">
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/*" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY"/>
        <security:custom-filter before="FIRST" ref="metadataGeneratorFilter"/>
        <security:custom-filter after="BASIC_AUTH_FILTER" ref="samlFilter"/>
    </security:http>

    <security:authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
        <security:authentication-provider ref="samlAuthenticationProvider"/>
    </security:authentication-manager>

    <bean id="samlAuthenticationProvider" class="org.springframework.security.saml.SAMLAuthenticationProvider">      

    </bean> 

    <bean id="samlEntryPoint" class="org.springframework.security.saml.SAMLEntryPoint">
        <property name="defaultProfileOptions">
            <bean class="org.springframework.security.saml.websso.WebSSOProfileOptions">
                <property name="includeScoping" value="false"/>
            </bean>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="metadataGeneratorFilter" class="org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.MetadataGeneratorFilter">
    <constructor-arg>
        <bean class="org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.MetadataGenerator"/>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

After such changes on the file, I compiled my project into war archive and tried to upload it to glassfish server. But then I got an error:

```
Error occurred during deployment: Exception while loading the app : java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: 
Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager#0': 
Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)' of type [org.springframework.security.config.authentication.AuthenticationManagerFactoryBean] while setting bean property 'parent'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: 
Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)': 
FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: 
Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.authenticationManager': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'samlAuthenticationProvider' while setting bean property 'providers' with key [0]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.
```

I found several topics with such problem but different libraries. No one could help me to solve my problem. It looks like that org.springframework.security.saml.SAMLAuthenticationProvider could not be found or resolved on the war archive. But I checked it manually and found it on the WEB-INF/lib folder spring-security-saml2-core-1.0.0-RC1-SNAPSHOT.jar. Also I checked inside jar archive and found SAMLAuthenticationProvider.class. Does anyone can help me to solve my problem. Maybe there are people that has experience with Spring security and saml extension.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I found that I was using incomplete securityContext.xml file

Comment: so can you update to show the complete securityContext.xml file

Comment: I'd also be very interested in this, as my securityContext seems complete and worked before, but not after upgrading to latest Spring-security 1.0.2.