# Spring 4 security configuration with spring security saml

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-saml

In my webapplication I'm using Spring and configuring it by java. What I'm trying to do now is to add spring security and a custom contextloaderlistener. It works just fine if I do it the "old" way. Via web.xml that is. But I would like to use java-configuration instead.

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<listener>
    <listener-class>my.custom.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

My ContextLoaderListener makes sure that my SecurityContext.xml is loaded and the SecurityContext.xml contains all the configuration for spring-security-saml. 
Below is just a snippet of the SecurityContext.xml

```
<context:annotation-config />
<context:component-scan base-package="org.springframework.security.saml" />

<security:http security="none" pattern="/css/**" />
.
.
.
```

I load my ContextLoaderListener by the below code:

```
public class DispatcherServletInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

@Override
protected void onStartup() {
    servletContext.addListener(CustomContextLoaderListener.class);
}
```

What I have accomplished so far is a webapplication that works in a way. I do get redirected to my Identity Provider and I get an successful authentication. 
The problem is that I need to disable csrf to get the saml-stuff working.

No problem I thought. I just added below class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable();
        super.configure(http);
    }
}
```

Not that simple because the above class is never triggered. What am I missing here?

Comment: Please see this post. It might be securitycontext.xml(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14441475/spring-saml-implementation-cannot-resolve-reference-to-bean)